# My discord.py bot is inconsistently adding roles to users when the command is triggered multiple times

Tags: discord.py

So I made this bot recently, and I seemed to notice and I spent a lot of research on why this issue occurs but could not find a clean good explanation of why my Bot does not role some users when the command is triggered. I've tried regenerating the token, fixing permissions, adjusting hierarchy, and it does not seem to fix the issue. The Code itself seems to be working fine, just very inconsistently.

here is my code:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import os
import replit
import keep_alive
from discord.utils import get

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("ready!")
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name= "over BFG"))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('<:Texans:783178718545707019> sign'):
    role = get(message.guild.roles, name= 'Houston Texans')
    fa = get(message.guild.roles, name= 'League Membership')
    member = message.mentions[0]
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await member.remove_roles(fa)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="✅ **Transaction Complete**", color=0xeeff00)
    embed.set_author(name="BFG Sign Bot")
    embed.add_field(name="⠀", value=f"Successfully Signed {member.mention} to the **Houston Texans** <:Texans:783178718545707019>", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="⠀", value=f"The BFG Houston Texans now have players on their active roster", inline=False)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    if fa not in member.roles:
      await member.remove_roles(role)
      await member.add_roles(fa)
      embed=discord.Embed(title="❌ **Transaction Declined**", color=0xeeff00)
      embed.set_author(name="BFG Sign Bot")
      embed.add_field(name="⠀", value=f"{member.mention} is already signed to a different team...", inline=False)
      await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
  if message.content.startswith('<:Texans:783178718545707019> release'):
    role = get(message.guild.roles, name= "Houston Texans")
    fa = get(message.guild.roles, name= "League Membership")
    member = message.mentions[0]
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    await member.add_roles(fa)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="✅ **Transaction Complete**", color=0xeeff00)
    embed.set_author(name="BFG Sign Bot")
    embed.add_field(name="⠀", value=f"Successfully Released {member.mention} from the **Houston Texans** <:Texans:783178718545707019>", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="⠀", value=f"The BFG Houston Texans now have players on their active roster", inline=False)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    if role not in member.roles:
      await member.remove_roles(fa)
      embed=discord.Embed(title="❌ **Transaction Declined**", color=0xeeff00)
      embed.set_author(name="BFG Sign Bot")
      embed.add_field(name="⠀", value=f"{member.mention} **you do not have permission to release this user...**", inline=False)
      await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

keep_alive.keep_alive()

client.run('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', bot=True, reconnect=True)
```

Comment: maybe you should need to enable SERVER MEMBERS INTENT in discord developer portal! [discord dev. portal >> App. >> select your app >> BOT section >> enable it] and try it again!

Comment: Why are you doing on_message?

Answer (score 0):

The error is really simple to fix i think. You only forgot

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

and you're ready to go.